# Change the starting measure point of a route - linear referencing

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing, route

I have a few routes created and stored as a feature class in a GDB.  When using the create route tool there is an option to choose the starting point of the routes.  However, I only have certain routes that start TOP LEFT (of the bounding rectangle), some start LOWER LEFT etc etc.  Is there a way to change the starting measure point after you have created routes or am I going to have to create routes in groups (those with lower left start points, the upperleft etc) and then merge afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I put the tracks from the GPS to Shapefile, and then into a GDB (creating routes preferred a feature class as opposed to an shp) that linear referencing wasn't necessary. I was just trying to create points at given intervals. USing the tracks before I turned them into routes and editing using the construct points worked a treat and got the start and end points correct every time

Comment: Just to add, if you have a line shape file and the line is the wrong way around (i.e. the red vertex is at the wrong end) you can:

start and edit session,
select the line in question,
right click and select edit vertices,
right click again and choose flip...

Now your start and end points are the right way around

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to create in groups. The arcgis tools are somewhat generic in my experience... The generic-ness is largely because linear referencing is implemented so differently between different organizations -- mostly due to the legacy nature of the systems and ground locations that retain the LRS measurements.

Comment: Thanks Awesomeo.  I actually discovered that if I put the tracks from the GPS to Shapefile, and then into a GDB (creating routes preferred a feature class as opposed to an shp) that linear referencing wasn't necessary.  I was just trying to create points at given intervals.  USing the tracks before I turned them into routes and editing using the construct points worked a treat and got the start and end points correct every time.